# php throwing error when trying to update fields within a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, edit

I am trying to edit fields within a database table called 'minutes', there are a number of sets of minutes but the code is working as follows... The session start sets the current user which is used in the queries below (currentUser=Bnumber)... When clicking on the edit button when on the 'viewstudentminutes.php' page it is throwing the following error 'Notice: Undefined index: Minute_ID in viewstudentminutes.php on line 179

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in viewstudentminutes.php:179 Stack trace: #0 viewstudentminutes.php(179): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM `...') #1 {main} thrown in viewstudentminutes.php on line 179'

Below is all the code on the minutes.php page and below is the code from the 'viewstudentminutes.php'

```
<?php
include ("dbConnect.php");
include ("studenthead.php");

session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION["sess_username"]))) header ("Location: index.php");
$currentUser=$_SESSION["sess_username"];   

if (isset($_POST['addMinute'])) {
$newB_number = $currentUser;
$newDate = $_POST['Date'];
$newTime = $_POST['Time'];
$newDiscussion = $_POST['Discussion'];
$newActions = $_POST['Actions'];
$newDateofnextmeeting = $_POST['Dateofnextmeeting'];
$newStatus = "Submitted";
$newE_number =  $_POST['E_number'];
$newSupervisor_comments = $_POST['Supervisor_comments'];



$dbQuery  = $db->prepare("insert into minute values (null, :newB_number, :newDate, :newTime, :newDiscussion, :newActions, :newDateofnextmeeting,  :newStatus, :newE_number, :newSupervisor_comments )");
$dbParams = array('newB_number'=>$newB_number, 'newDate'=>$newDate, 'newTime'=>$newTime, 'newDiscussion'=>$newDiscussion, 'newActions'=>$newActions, 'newDateofnextmeeting'=>$newDateofnextmeeting, 'newStatus'=>$newStatus, 'newE_number'=>$newE_number, 'newSupervisor_comments'=>$newSupervisor_comments);
$dbQuery->execute($dbParams);

$lastInserted = $db->lastInsertId();
}

if (isset($_POST['deleteMinuteID'])) {
$ID = $_POST['deleteMinuteID'];

$dbQuery  = $db->prepare("delete from minute where ID=:ID");
$dbParams = array('ID'=>$ID);
$dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
}


if (isset($_POST['editCommitID'])) {
$ID           = $_POST['editCommitID'];
$editB_number = $_POST['editB_number'];
$editDate  = $_POST['editDate'];
$editTime  = $_POST['editTime'];
$editDiscussion  = $_POST['editDiscussion'];
$editActions = $_POST['editActions'];
$editDateofnextmeeting = $_POST['editDateofnextmeeting'];
$editStatus = $_POST['editStatus'];
$editE_number = $_POST['editE_number'];
$editSupervisor_comments = $_POST['editSupervisor_comments'];


$dbQuery  = $db->prepare("update minute set B_number=:B_number, Date=:Date, Time=:Time, Discussion=:Discussion, Actions=:Actions, Dateofnextmeeting=:Dateofnextmeeting, Status=:Status, E_number=:E_number, Supervisor_comments=:Supervisor_comments where ID=:ID");
$dbParams = array('ID'=>$ID, 'B_number'=>$editB_number, 'Date'=>$editDate, 'Time'=>$editTime, 'Discussion'=>$editDiscussion, 'Actions'=>$editActions, 'Dateofnextmeeting'=>$editDateofnextmeeting, 'Status'=>$editStatus, 'E_number'=>$editE_number, 'Supervisor_comments'=>$editSupervisor_comments);
$dbQuery->execute($dbParams);

header("location: minutes.php");
exit();
}


?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Minutes</title>

<h2>Minutes</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <th>B Number</th><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Discussion</th>    <th>Actions</th><th>Date of next meeting</th><th>Status</th><th>Supervisor</th><th>Supervisor comments</th>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
$dbQuery = $db->prepare("select * from minute where '$currentUser'=B_number ");
$dbQuery->execute();

$numMinutes = $dbQuery->rowCount();

echo "<p>There are $numMinutes sets of minutes in the system</p>";

$oddRow=true;
while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ID       = $dbRow['ID'];
    $B_number = $dbRow['B_number'];
    $Date  = $dbRow['Date'];
    $Time  = $dbRow['Time'];
    $Discussion = $dbRow['Discussion'];
    $Actions = $dbRow['Actions'];
    $Dateofnextmeeting = $dbRow['Dateofnextmeeting'];
    $Status = $dbRow['Status'];
    $E_number = $dbRow['E_number'];
    $Supervisor_comments = $dbRow['Supervisor_comments'];


    if ($oddRow) $rowClass="odd"; else $rowClass="even";
    $oddRow=!$oddRow;

    if (isset($_POST['editMinuteID']) && $_POST['editMinuteID']==$ID) {
        echo "<tr class='$rowClass '>
              <form style='display:inline' method='post' action='minutes.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='editCommitID' value='$ID'>
                <td><input type='varchar' name='editB_number' value='$B_number'></td>
                <td><input type='date' name='editDate' value='$Date'></td>
                <td><input type='time' name='editTime' value='$Time'></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='editDiscussion' value='$Discussion'></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='editActions' value='$Actions'></td>
                <td><input type='date' name='editDateofnextmeeting' value='$Dateofnextmeeting'></td>
                <td><input type='enum' name='editStatus' value='$Status'></td>
                <td><input type='varchar' name='editE_number' value='$E_number'></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='editSupervisor_comments' value='$Supervisor_comments'></td>
                <td colspan='2'><input type='image' src='edit.png'>
             </form>
             </tr>";      
    } else {

        echo "<tr class='$rowClass'><td>$B_number</td><td>$Date</td><td>$Time</td><td>$Discussion</td><td>$Actions</td><td>$Dateofnextmeeting</td><td>$Status</td><td>$E_number</td><td>$Supervisor_comments</td>
                  <td class='operation'>
                     <form class='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php'>
                     <input type='hidden' name='editMinute_ID' value='$ID'>
                     <input type='image' src='edit.png' style='padding-top:7px'>
                     </form></td>
                  <td class='operation'>
                     <form class='display:inline' method='post' action='minutes.php'   
                           onsubmit='return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")'>
                     <input type='hidden' name='deleteMinuteID' value='$ID'>
                     <input type='image' src='delete.png' style='padding-top:7px'>
                     </form></td>
                     <td class='operation'>
                     <form class='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php' onsubmit='viewstudentminutes.php'>
                    <input type='image' src='view.png' style='padding-top:7px'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='Minute_ID' value='" . $ID . "'>
</form></td>
 </tr>";
}         
}


?>
```

and the corresponding code within the 'viewstudentminutes'

```
<?php
include ("dbConnect.php");
include ("studenthead.php");

session_start();
if (!(isset($_SESSION["sess_username"]))) header ("Location: index.php");

$currentUser=$_SESSION["sess_username"];   

if (isset($_POST['addMinute'])) {
$newB_number = $currentUser;
$newDate = $_POST['Date'];
$newTime = $_POST['Time'];
$newDiscussion = $_POST['Discussion'];
$newActions = $_POST['Actions'];
$newDateofnextmeeting = $_POST['Dateofnextmeeting'];
$newStatus = "Submitted";
$newE_number =  $_POST['E_number'];
$newSupervisor_comments = "  ";




$dbQuery  = $db->prepare("insert into minute values (null, :newB_number, :newDate, :newTime, :newDiscussion, :newActions, :newDateofnextmeeting, :newStatus, :newE_number, :newSupervisor_comments )");
$dbParams = array('$newB_number'=>$newB_number, 'newDate'=>$newDate, 'newTime'=>$newTime, 'newDiscussion'=>$newDiscussion, 'newActions'=>$newActions, 'newDateofnextmeeting'=>$newDateofnextmeeting, 'newStatus'=>$newStatus, 'newE_number'=>$newE_number, 'newSupervisor_comments'=>$newSupervisor_comments);
$dbQuery->execute($dbParams);

$lastInserted = $db->lastInsertId();
}



if (isset($_POST['editCommitID'])) {
$ID           = $_POST['editCommitID'];
$editB_number = $_POST['editB_number'];
$editDate  = $_POST['editDate'];
$editTime  = $_POST['editTime'];
$editDiscussion  = $_POST['editDiscussion'];
$editActions = $_POST['editActions'];
$editDateofnextmeeting = $_POST['editDateofnextmeeting'];
$editStatus = $_POST['editStatus'];
$editE_number = $_POST['editE_number'];
$editSupervisor_comments = $_POST['editSupervisor_comments'];


$dbQuery  = $db->prepare("update minute set B_number=:B_number, Date=:Date, Time=:Time, Discussion=:Discussion, Actions=:Actions, Dateofnextmeeting=:Dateofnextmeeting, Status=:Status, E_number=:E_number, Supervisor_comments=:Supervisor_comments where ID=:ID");
$dbParams = array('ID'=>$ID, 'B_number'=>$editB_number, 'Date'=>$editDate, 'Time'=>$editTime, 'Discussion'=>$editDiscussion, 'Actions'=>$editActions, 'Dateofnextmeeting'=>$editDateofnextmeeting, 'Status'=>$editStatus, 'E_number'=>$editE_number, 'Supervisor_comments'=>$editSupervisor_comments);
$dbQuery->execute($dbParams);

header("location: viewstudentminutes.php");
exit();
}



?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Minutes</title>

<h2>Minutes</h2>
<table class="table table-condensed">
<?php 


$dbQuery= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Minute` WHERE `B_number` = '" .     $currentUser . "' AND `id` = " . $_POST['Minute_ID']);
$dbQuery->execute();


$oddRow=true;
while ($dbRow = $dbQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $ID       = $dbRow['ID'];
    $B_number = $dbRow['B_number'];
    $Date  = $dbRow['Date'];
    $Time  = $dbRow['Time'];
    $Discussion = $dbRow['Discussion'];
    $Actions = $dbRow['Actions'];
    $Dateofnextmeeting = $dbRow['Dateofnextmeeting'];
    $Status = $dbRow['Status'];
    $E_number = $dbRow['E_number'];
    $Supervisor_comments = $dbRow['Supervisor_comments'];


    if ($oddRow) $rowClass="odd"; else $rowClass="even";
    $oddRow=!$oddRow;

    if (isset($_POST['editMinuteID']) && $_POST['editMinuteID']==$id) {
        echo "<tr class='$rowClass'>
              <form style='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php'>
                <input type='hidden' name='editCommitID' value='$ID'>
                 <tr><td colspan='2'><input type='image' src='edit.png'></tr>
                 <tr><th>BNumber</th><td><input type='varchar' name='editB_number' value='$B_number'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Date</th><td><input type='date' name='editDate' value='$Date'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Time</th><td><input type='time' name='editTime' value='$Time'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Discussion</th><td><input type='text' name='editDiscussion' value='$Discussion'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Actions</th><td><input type='text' name='editActions' value='$Actions'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Date of Next Meeting</th><td><input type='date' name='editDateofnextmeeting' value='$Dateofnextmeeting'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Status</th><td><input type='enum' name='editStatus' value='$Status'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>E Number</th><td><input type='varchar' name='editE_number' value='$E_number'></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Supervisor Comments</th><td><input type='text' name='editSupervisor_comments' value='$Supervisor_comments'></td></tr>

             </form>
             </tr>";      
    } else {
        echo "<tr class='$rowClass'>
                <td class='operation'>
                     <form class='display:inline' method='post' action='viewstudentminutes.php'>
                     <input type='hidden' name='editMinute_ID' value='$ID'>
                     <input type='image' src='edit.png' style='padding-top:7px'>
                     </form></td>
                <tr><th>BNumber</th><td>$B_number</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Date</th><td>$Date</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Time</th><td>$Time</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Discussion</th><td>$Discussion</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Actions</th><td>$Actions</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Date of Next Meeting</th><td>$Dateofnextmeeting</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Status</th><td>$Status</td></tr>
                <tr><th>E Number</th><td>$E_number</td></tr>
                <tr><th>Supervisor Comments</th>   <td>$Supervisor_comments</td></tr>
              </tr>";
    }         
}

?>
</table>
```

Comment: $dbQuery= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Minute` WHERE `B_number` = '" . $currentUser . "' AND `id` = " . $_POST['Minute_ID']);    However I need this statement as it prints out the selected minute....

Comment: Your form in `viewstudentminutes.php` doesn't have a field with a name of `Minute_ID`, so when you try and use it after the form is submitted, `$_POST['Minute_ID']` doesn't exist. You get a message from PHP about an undefined index and a complaint from MySQl about a syntax error because your `SELECT` query is malformed as a result of the missing variable.

Comment: Ok have you any idea how to fix this? the id is auto-incremented and the user never enters this, are you meaning i should put a line like this within the form... <tr><th>MinuteID</th><td><input type='varchar' name='editMinute_ID' value='$ID'></td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the query line as below:

```
$dbQuery= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Minute` WHERE `B_number` = '" .     $currentUser . "' AND `id` = " . $_POST['editMinute_ID']);
```

Comment: You can print the $_REQUEST array to find out the correct field name

Comment: I am using the correct field name though? can you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: I mean to say that after printing the $_REQUEST array, you can be sure of whether you are using the correct field name. $_REQUEST will show all the fields that are submitted. Can you print what you are getting after printing $_REQUEST?

Comment: I changed $_POST['editMinute_ID'] , to $_POST['ID'] and the corresponding variables as like. I tried print_r($_POST); and it printed Array (). So an array with nothing in it?! Im very confused, is there anyway you can post an example of what i should be doing to show only the set of minutes clicked on and allows the user to edit them? PLEASE